# AngularJS Dynamically changing field value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For purposes of an example here is a very basic piece of code. CodePen example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOYgEa

```
{{name}}
```

is linked to

```
<input ng-model="name" type="text" placeholder="" id="name" />
```

So when some text is typed in the input field, it is reflected on the page.  However if the value of `#name` is set dynamically, in this case by pressing the button, then `{{name}}` does not update.

I know there is an 'angular' way of doing this, however this is just an example because in reality the dynamic change will be from a jQuery callback.

I've tried to add a `$scope.watch` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: `<input type="button" id="mybutton" value="Demo" ng-click="name='Demo'">`

Comment: This works as expected, but the dynamic change (in this instance represented by a button click), will be from a jQuery callback.

Comment: @Rob do you have a case where you wanted to manipulated DOM, from outer context of angular...?

Comment: @Pankaj I have a DOM element which will be changed dynamically, and depending on the value of that element will in turn alter the angular $scope

Comment: @Rob would you mind to explain it further.. I don't really understand it.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var app = angular.module('demo',[]);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {

  $("#mybutton").on("click", function(){
    //$("#name").val("Demo");
    $scope.name = "Demo"
    $scope.$apply() // we use $scope.$apply() which will call $scope.$digest()
  });

 $scope.name = "Enter a value";

 $scope.$watch('name',function(newValue, oldValue){
        $scope.name(newValue);
    }); 

});

$(document).ready(function(){



});
```

removing code from **$(document).ready** bcoz **$scope is not accessible** there .

EDIT :  **you can also use ng-click**

In HTML

```
<input type="button" id="mybutton" value="Demo" ng-click="someFunction()">
```

In controller :

```
    $scope.someFunction = function(){
          $scope.name = "Demo" 
   }
```

Comment: there is no need to use `"click"` handle of jQuery here with angular.. I'd say use `ng-click` instead

Comment: @p2 I understand man.. I think OP has code which wanted to manipulate scope from outer context of angular,,

Comment: you don't need $scope.apply() for simple task. when you are in angular scope binding event using jquery is not the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to decouple the jQuery callback from Angular, you could simply trigger the `change` event, which will cause Angular to process the new value as if the user had typed it in the box:

```
var app = angular.module('demo',[]);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
 $scope.name = "Enter a value";
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mybutton").on("click", function() {
    $("#name").val("Demo").trigger('change');
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOYMBb

Answer (score 1):

Use trigger - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/oxjBVa)

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#mybutton").on("click", function(){
    $("#name").val("Demo");
    $("#name").trigger('input');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery event binding when working inside the Angular scope.

When you update model values in angularjs, it kicks digest cycle to update $scope variables.

So, when you are working outside angular scope and try to invoke any event, digest cylce does not kicks and the result is model values are not udpated.

Below is udpated angular code: Added update method in scope and removed $scope.watch.

```
app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
 $scope.name = "Enter a value";

  $scope.update  = function(value){
    $scope.name  = value;
  }

});
```

Updated HTML: Added ng-click event.

```
 <input type="button" id="mybutton" ng-click="update('Demo');"  value="Demo">
```

Here is the nice article, if you want to dig more in deep.

http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/